# Using RegularExpressionValidator for numbers and "," character only in textbox

Tags: asp.net

Visual Studio 2013, Asp.net, webforms.
Trying to control input into textbox, numbers and "," character only. I have the following code:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" ControlToValidate="txtOfferPrice" runat="server" ErrorMessage="فقط عدد وارد کنید!" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\d+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: What doesn't Work, please describe your problem, preferable with some showing what you have tried and what didn't Work.

Comment: Try: ValidationExpression="\d+(,\d+)?"

Comment: in this ValidationExpression="\d+" i can limit only numbers but i need limit numbers and comma "," character , but in your sample when i insert comma it give a error

Comment: Try: ValidationExpression="[\d,]+"

Comment: ty but how i can check space between input value? this expression does not work for space

Comment: To allow Space, simply add a Space between the brackets.

Comment: my means, i don't want to allow space